# Angularjs directive attribute can't wait for loading data

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have a directive for showing a 'share to social networks menu'. It works fine in normal page but when i use it on a lightbox (that fetchs it's data after clicking on an item), it fails to pass attributes to share menu directive without any error. The variables are empty.

```
<item-actions data-itemid="{{popup.id}}"></item-actions>
```

Directive:

```js
var itemActions_tmpl = 
    '<div>' +
        // share button
        '<div class="share-w">' +
            '<button type="button" class="button radius share" value="share" >' +
            '</button>' +
            '<ul>' +
                '<li><a target="_blank" data-ng-href="{{::fblink}}">Facebook</a></li>' +
                '<li><a target="_blank" data-ng-href="{{::gplink}}">Google +</a></li>' +
                '<li><a target="_blank" data-ng-href="{{::twlink}}">Twitter</a></li>' +
            '</ul>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

jApp.directive('itemActions', ['APP_CONFIG', function(APP_CONFIG){
    return {
        replace:true,
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: itemActions_tmpl,
        link: function(scope, Elem, Attrs, controller) {

            scope.fblink = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + APP_CONFIG.BASE_ITEM_URL + Attrs.itemid;
            scope.gplink = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + APP_CONFIG.BASE_ITEM_URL + Attrs.itemid;
            scope.twlink = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + APP_CONFIG.BASE_ITEM_URL + Attrs.itemid;
        }
    };
}]);
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: can you paste your lightbox code ?

Comment: By using $q and waiting for data and then opening popup problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used $q and problem solved. Just waiting for data and then opening popup.